# Why "alias X conflicts with an alias in the same statement" on aliased CTE use but not aliased table use?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I wonder why the below statement causes this error with at least the Win32 Firebird WI-V2.5.7.27050 and WI-V2.5.2.26540 versions.

```
 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 alias TRIPLEDIGITS conflicts with an alias in the same statement
```

Unlinke many errors in SQL statements, the above error does not indicate the line that causes it, but with some fiddling I found the line marked with a comment causes it.

Query having one CTE unaliased and an the same CTE aliased:

```
with 
  recursive 
  tripledigits(n) as (        
    select 0
    from rdb$database
    union all
    select tripledigits.n + 1
    from tripledigits
    where tripledigits.n < 999
  ),
  sextupledigits(n) as (
    select tripledigits.n 
          + tripledigits000.n * 1000
    from tripledigits
    cross join tripledigits tripledigits000 -- causes "Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 alias TRIPLEDIGITS conflicts with an alias in the same statement"
    order by tripledigits.n 
          + tripledigits000.n * 1000
  )
select sextupledigits.n 
from sextupledigits
order by sextupledigits.n
```

It also fails when moving the failing query out of the `sextupledigits` CTE into the main query:

```
with 
  recursive 
  tripledigits(n) as (        
    select 0
    from rdb$database
    union all
    select tripledigits.n + 1
    from tripledigits
    where tripledigits.n < 999
  )
select tripledigits.n 
      + tripledigits000.n * 1000
from tripledigits
cross join tripledigits tripledigits000 -- causes "Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 alias TRIPLEDIGITS conflicts with an alias in the same statement"
order by tripledigits.n 
      + tripledigits000.n * 1000
```

Whereas using the below using an unaliased table and the same table aliased:

```
select rdb$database.rdb$relation_id  + rd.rdb$relation_id * 1000
from rdb$database
cross join rdb$database rd
```

**Why is my CTE based query throwing the error?**

I know at least two workarounds (see below), but for documentation purposes and posterity I'd like an answer to the question.

Workaround 1: alias both CTE uses

```
with 
  recursive
  tripledigits(n) as (        
    select 0
    from rdb$database
    union all
    select tripledigits.n + 1
    from tripledigits
    where tripledigits.n < 999
  ),
  sextupledigits(n) as (
    select tripledigitsBare.n 
          + tripledigits000.n * 1000
    from tripledigits tripledigitsBare
    cross join tripledigits tripledigits000
    order by tripledigitsBare.n 
          + tripledigits000.n * 1000
  )
select sextupledigits.n 
from sextupledigits
order by sextupledigits.n
```

Workaround 2: use an intermediate CTE

```
with 
  recursive
  tripledigits(n) as (        
    select 0
    from rdb$database
    union all
    select tripledigits.n + 1
    from tripledigits
    where tripledigits.n < 999
  ),
  tripledigits000(n) as (
    select tripledigits.n * 1000
    from tripledigits
  ),
  sextupledigits(n) as (
    select tripledigits.n 
          + tripledigits000.n
    from tripledigits
    cross join tripledigits000
    order by tripledigits.n 
          + tripledigits000.n
  )
select sextupledigits.n 
from sextupledigits
order by sextupledigits.n
```

I've reported it in the Firebird tracker as [CORE-5519](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-5519).

Comment: Have you tried with a more recent version like 2.5.7 or 3.0.2? Also, consider reporting a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/ if reproducible in a newer version. It sounds like a parser bug to me.

Comment: I will do and update the question accordingly. It is important for documentation purposes to know which versions fail. I will follow up on the tracker as well. I'm glad the Firebird Jira tracker - unlike the InterBase one -
 *is* indexed in Google Search.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel reported as http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-5519